# PHP/MySQL: Why is my query only returning the first row?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, methods

Why is my method only returning the first row of my table? I can't understand why and it's driving me nuts. I'm sure it's something very simple.

```
public function getTitlesForRegistrationForm() {
    $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT UserTitleID, UserTitleName FROM UserTitles");
    $i=0;
    $array[0] = "No result";
    foreach($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
        $array[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$result->fetch()` returns a single row with each call. You are only calling it once …

Comment: Are you using PDO library? I think you should use fetchAll() instead of fetch()

Comment: Have you run the query with a tool like phpMyAdmin to see what the result is?  It's possible your query has a single result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `fetch()` inside a `while` loop. It will return only one row each time it is called.

I've also taken the liberty of refactoring away your `$i` counter. Instead the `No result` is appended onto the array in the first position (for whatever purpose you planned to use it), and subsequent rows are appended on with `[]`.

```
public function getTitlesForRegistrationForm() {
    $array = array();
    $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT UserTitleID, UserTitleName FROM UserTitles");

    // Why are you putting No Result onto the array?
    // I've left it in, but it doesn't make sense to me.
    $array[] = "No result";
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $array[] = $row;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361894/php-mysql-how-to-get-multiple-values-from-a-php-database-method/9361921#comment11821387_9361921

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I understood why you're accumulating the result set onto an array, I don't understand why you're adding "No result" at the beginning.

Comment: Ah, I see. Error handing, so I can see that something isn't working. Probably not the best way. There's no need for it, so your answer is actually best (and first). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It may be because your `$result->fetch()` call doesn't return an iterable value, but either a result row or `FALSE`. PHP's `foreach` only works on iterable values. Updating your code to something like this should do the trick:

```
public function getTitlesForRegistrationForm() {
    $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT UserTitleID, UserTitleName FROM UserTitles");
    $i=0;
    $array[0] = "No result";
    while (($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) {
        $array[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are using `fetch()`. You need `fetchall()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

[edit]Wow. I need to learn to type faster.

Comment: You're right, that did work... sort of. I got some crap in the Array.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try while instead of foreach. Foreach only iterates over a single row that is returned.
code:

```
while($row = fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $array[$i] = $row;
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the `fetch` method with `fetchAll`

Comment: You're right, that did work... sort of. I got some crap in the Array.